# Use subquery in WHERE caluse in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

I have two tables as user and userGroup related such that each user can be assigned to one or more userGroup. The user table contains a foreign key as group_id when contains comma separated values of the userGroup id.
I want to fetch the user details and the comma separated group_name he is related to in a single query. Is there any method I can achieve this in SQL?
The fields of user table are: (id, uname, group_id)
userGroup: (id, group_name)

What I want is I get uname, group_name, user.id, group.id in a single SQL query.

I have tried the following query but it gives me error

```
SELECT t1.uname, group_concat(t.group_name) FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN user_group t2
ON t1.group_id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.id IN t1.group_id
```

Comment: Following on from @user2864740's comment, you need to normalize into three tables - User(UserId, Name), Group (GroupId, Name), and UserGroup(UserId, GroupId).

Comment: Normalize your tables. Using comma separated lists to store the foreign key will lead to a lot of problems and poor query productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.uname, GROUP_CONCAT(t.group_name) AS group_name 
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN user_group t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, t1.group_id)
GROUP BY t1.id;
```